# My iCloud email and password

Tags: icloud, email, password

My iCloud account is under a @yahoo.com address which was canceled by yahoo for some reason, and the security questions do not seem like ones I would have chosen. So I cannot get my back up from iCloud as I have just purchased a new iPhone. Is it possible to get my old password so I may change my iCloud email and password?

Comment: If you can't remember your iCloud password (which will continue to work regardless of your access to the associated email), and you have no access to the email to recover the password, then your best bet is to contact Apple's iCloud support: https://www.apple.com/support/icloud/contact/

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your system has "saved" your  iCloud log in information in you keyhain.

Open it and type iCloud in the search.